# NodeJS - POST - Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: node.js

After the whole afternoon yesterday and some hours this morning I keep got the issue.

I updated all the packages needed.
I send POST with PostMan, using a **header Content-Type:application/json** and **body (Key=id) and (Value=32)** ( please check the screenshot below).

Code used :

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const router = express.Router();
var app = express();
app.use(router);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
var hostname = 'localhost';
var port = 3000;

app.listen(port, hostname, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("Server OK at http://" + hostname + ":" + port);
    }
});
router.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log('' + req.body.id);
});
```

I tried on PostMap this :

[POST send from PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCcAA.png) ;
[Second try from PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UirbA.png)

I used Key=id Value=32
but also "id" and 32
from the form-data and the three others too (x-www-form-urlencoded, raw, ...)

Error :

> TypeError: **Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**
>       at router.post (C:\SVDJS\test\simpleTest.js:19:30)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\SVDJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (C:\SVDJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (C:\SVDJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\SVDJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at C:\SVDJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (C:\SVDJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (C:\SVDJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (C:\SVDJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>       at router (C:\SVDJS\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

I have read the most of posts about this problem findable on internet, please don't redirect if not justified.

If someone can help me it would be greatful. Thanks.

Comment: I just want to say Hi, because the post seems to remove it automatically.

Comment: `req.body` is undefined. Try printing `req`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.
it displays [object Object] : https://imgur.com/XU6nV8R

I tried also console.log('' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
but it displays undefined.

Comment: What about `console.log(JSON.stringify(req))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, since you use `app.use(bodyParser.json());` you should send json via postman as you did on your second screenshot. http://joxi.ru/1A5oo90iKloLVm

Second thing is you using your route before your middlewares

You did:

```
app.use(router);
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
```

So body not parsed yet

And it should be:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(router);
```

Consistency is important in nodejs

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Indeed the POST send from PostMan had a mistake, the Raw structure was the one to use.
And indeed, the second thing was the deepest problem there.

Resolved.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`req.body` (in the line `console.log('' + req.body.id);`) is `undefined`. Probably the request you receive does not contains any body at all. Or the given body can't be parsed according to its Content-Type.

According to your screenshot, you are not sending a valid JSON. `form-data` of PostMan does not send JSON. If you want to send a JSON, select `raw` and write the JSON: `{"id":32}`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I edited the post adding the screenshots related to my PostMan send about this. In fact when I said "id:32" it's just the key and value because I didn't write directely id:32 but I completed the field Key with id and the field Value with 32.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that this one was the good one ^^
It shows the same error.
https://imgur.com/Lq6WncU
(this is not "id" = 32 but "id":32 but same error)