# Cannot post data although it worked yesterday

Tags: node.js, express

Yesterday I made a simple API, just for testing. There I could do everything, get, post, delete and patch. But today I can only get and delete. When I want to make a post I get an error and I don't understand it, because yesterday it worked fine.

## Posts

### Post 1

Here is my post:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    });
    try {
        const savedPost = await post.save();
        res.json(savedPost);
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({
            message: err
        });
    }
});
```

### Post 2

I made another post but this also doesn't work:

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const postData = {
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    }
    Post.findOne({
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description
    })
    .then(post => {
        if (!post) {
            Post.create(postData);
            res.json(postData);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send(err);
    })
})
```

## Error

Here is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at router.post (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\routes\posts.js:35:25)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)
```

## Schema

So it says the title is undefinied. In my model I defined it as a string:

```
const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

## Postman

In postman I make a post with a raw body and the type JSON(application/json):

```
{
    "title": "test",
    "description": "this is a test"
}
```

How can I define the title?

## EDIT

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49025573/nodejs-post-cannot-read-property-x-of-undefined?rq=1) on Stackoverflow. I tried this solution, but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I don't think it's saying "title" is undefined, it's saying that it's trying to access a property called "title" from an undefined object. It looks like "req.body" is undefined. The stack trace tells you where the error is occuring: D:\Sonstiges\VUE_JS\rest_api\routes\posts.js line 35. Can you find which line this is?

Comment: @sheltond It's the line where it says `title: req.body.title`. I removed the `.body` part but then I realised this doesn't make any sense because I will add exactly nothing with it.

Comment: Are you using the "body-parser" middleware? The problem could be to do with the ordering of your middleware (the body-parser one needs to come before your router).

Comment: @sheltond yes I do